# How to make work DataURL and Lightbox together

Tags: vb.net

I want to use **Lightbox**. Images are binding from back-end in VB.NET(database-sqlserver).

Here is HTML which is inside a datalist controler:

```
<a href='<%# Eval("images")%>' rel="lightbox[Brussels]">
<img alt="" src='<%# Eval("images")%>' height="150" width="150" class=" img img-thumbnail" />
</a>
```

I am not storing the images filepath. Just storing the images in **varbinary(max)** So cant give **href** attribute of Link.

I referenced hyperlink **href** attribute via **dataurl**.Its value is coming in **base64**

```
dr("images") = "data:Image/png;base64," & Convert.ToBase64String(imgbyte)
```

where **imgbyte** is byte array().

Whenever I am clicking on the Image(binded from database),it should come in front using Lightbox.
But problem is arousing as image poping out is partial clear or 30% clear rest blured or nothing at all.Don't know the exact reason why?

I have read somewhere that Internet Explorer 6 or 7 is not using dataurl. And it can show upto 32kb size image. But I have checked it in IE11.It does't work.

Any possibility how can we show images  of big size using dataurl in LightBox?

Any other possibility how can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see is to implement a custom endpoint, say [Generic Handler](http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/ASP/Generic_Handlers_(ASHX_Files).html) or a more tailored one, which returns a proper binary stream by providing the Identifier of the corresponding image.

For example

```
/MyCustomImageProvider.ashx?Id=1
```

This endpoint will be reachable via URL and such URL can be fed to LightBox, while keeping your images stored in a Table rather than a physical file.

In the end, your aspx code could like the following

```
<a href='<%# Eval("images")%>' rel="lightbox[Brussels]">
     <img alt="" src="/MyCustomImageProvider.ashx?Id=<%# Eval("imageId")%>" height="150" width="150" class=" img img-thumbnail" />
</a>
```

Comment: I try this.. but It does't work... still same status.. blurred image !!What else can we do @Matteo Marciano-MSCP

Comment: @Keezy- I see you post http://stackoverflow.com/q/33646977/6517368. You too had a same problem.I have as similar issue..I used FancyBox too but problem remain same. It works fine with Mozilla FireFox,Chrome.Did you solve this?